# Why does this IF statement not require an End IF

Tags: loops, if-statement, excel, vba

I am using the following snapshot of code to loop through files in a folder, it has a simple `If` to check if there are files in the folder then exits if there aren't. I've realised it does not require an `End If` at the end to compile correctly. However, I want to add a `msgbox` explaining why it has exited and to do so I need to introduce an `End If` to my code.

Why is that?

**Original Code**

```
If Len(strfilename) = 0 Then Exit Sub
    Do Until strfilename = ""
       'Do some stuff
    strfilename = Dir()
Loop
```

**With MsgBox**

```
If Len(strfilename) = 0 Then
    MsgBox ("No Files Found")
    Exit Sub
Else
    Do Until strfilename = ""
        'Do some stuff
    strfilename = Dir()
    Loop
End If
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a single line form of `if`:

```
if (expr) then X
```

where `X` must be on the same *line*, which is nice for single expressions:

```
if 1=1 then exit sub
```

or the odd but legal (using `:` continuation character)

```
if 1 = 1 Then MsgBox ("No Files Found"): Exit Sub
```

which is better written using the more readable block form that requires an `end if` to tell the compiler when the `if` block ends:

```
if 1 = 1 Then 
   MsgBox ("No Files Found")
   Exit Sub
end if
```